# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' while executing in SST Python

Tags: python, selenium, sst

THIS OCCURS IN FIREFOX ONLY: In a previous question, I had run into the issue where SST 0.2.4 is not compatible with Selenium 2.44.0. So I downgraded to Selenium 2.43.0. I now have a new issue that I'm confused about. I'm receiving the following error message:

```
_StringException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sst\cases.py", line 75, in setUp
self.start_browser()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sst\cases.py", line 107, in start_browser
logger.debug('Browser started: %s' % (self.browser.name))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

The code that it is referencing in the cases.py file in the Lib/SST folder is below:

```
    def start_browser(self):
    max_attempts = 5
    for nb_attempts in range(1, max_attempts):
        try:
            logger.debug('Starting browser (attempt: %d)' % (nb_attempts,))
            self._start_browser()
            break
        except exceptions.WebDriverException:
            if nb_attempts >= max_attempts:
                raise
    logger.debug('Browser started: %s' % (self.browser.name))
```

My code looks like the following:

```
import unittest
from sst.actions import *
from sst import cases, config, browsers

class TestMyTest(cases.SSTTestCase):

   def test_mytestcase_home_page(self):
    config.results_directory = "C:/Users/Brenda/test/SST-Test-Project/results"
    go_to('http://www.myhomepage.com')
    assert_title_contains('My Home Page')
    take_screenshot(filename='home_page.png',add_timestamp=True)
    assert_element(tag='a', text='Log in')
```

I keep thinking that the solution to this is fairly simple, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I'll also add the note that when running sst-run MySSTTest in the command line, it looks like it is attempting to start the browser without success. My code was working prior to the holiday break at which time it seems to have broken.

EDITED 3-Dec-2014: I wanted to add that I can successfully execute the test in Chrome and IE. This issue is with Firefox ONLY in a Windows 7 environment. It was successfully executed on a Mac OS in all 3 browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think cases.py codes has possibility cannot get browser object when it runs _start_browser

method

```
def _start_browser(self):
    self.browser_factory.setup_for_test(self)
    self.browser = self.browser_factory.browser()

def start_browser(self):
    max_attempts = 5
    for nb_attempts in range(1, max_attempts):
        try:
            logger.debug('Starting browser (attempt: %d)' % (nb_attempts,))
            self._start_browser()
            break
        except exceptions.WebDriverException:
            if nb_attempts >= max_attempts:
                raise
    logger.debug('Browser started: %s' % (self.browser.name))
```

Comment: That's my assumption, but why? I didn't have to make any modifications before when I executed the test previously.

Answer (score 0):

- The main problem: `if nb_attempts >= max_attempts:` has no effect. `nb_attempts` only goes up to `max_attempts-1`. I would use `continue` and re-raise the exception in an `else` clause instead:

  ```
  logger.debug('Starting browser')
  e = None
  for _ in range(max_attempts):
      try:
          self._start_browser()
          break
      except exceptions.WebDriverException,e:
          continue
  else:
      raise e
  ```

  ("`_`" is an idiom for an unused variable)
- Even with that fix, `self.browser` can still be `None` if `browser_factory.browser()` returns `None`.

Comment: I'm a little nervous about changing that specific code as it is the out of the box file that comes with SST. I didn't know if I would need to update my own code to pull in the "name" attribute or not. And if so, how?

Comment: I made the edits, and the error message now reads `WebDriverException: Message: 'Cannot connect to the selenium extension, Firefox output:...`

Comment: That only shows the quality of code in SST. Maybe you'd go with plain `selenium` with `unittest` (e.g. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html) - I cannot readily see what SST has that they haven't.

Comment: "Just what it reads on the lid" (c) AFAIK you need to start a server that scripts in the browser will get commands from as well. You'd better consult a related HOWTO on how to do it with your particular setup. Anyway, troubleshooting this further is out of scope of this question.